# Autohotkey capslock remapping and use as a modifier

Tags: autohotkey

Setting up the following script:

```
#persistent
SetCapsLockState, AlwaysOff
CapsLock::Esc

Capslock & j::Send {Blind}{Down DownTemp}
Capslock & j up::Send {Blind}{Down Up}
```

I am having a problem, where if I click `Shift-Caps-j`, or just `Shift-Esc`, it will activate Caps (instead of highlighting the next line).

I do not understand why this problem does not happen [here](https://gist.github.com/Danik/5808330). Any ideas or fixes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default AutoHotKey only enables a hotkey if that exact combination of keys is pressed, no variation allowed. To achieve the "select one line below" effect, you should be using the `*` wildcard modifier which makes the hotkey work even if extra keys are pressed, like this:

```
#persistent
SetCapsLockState, AlwaysOff
*CapsLock::Esc

*Capslock & j::Send {Blind}{Down DownTemp}
*Capslock & j up::Send {Blind}{Down Up}
```

Read more about it here: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#wildcard

Also, if you would like to use a modifier key on multiple hotkeys (like CapsLock in you case) I would recommend combining the `#If` environment with the `GetKeyState` command like you can see in my script that I use to turn some keys into arrows while a button is pressed down and many more extras.

https://gist.github.com/Isti115/0b657e7d0a50c96dd3806e86951f5421

---

*Edit:* Hmm, it seems like the asterisk shouldn't be necessary for combined keys.
The documentation: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#combo_mods says that `Unlike a normal hotkey, custom combinations act as though they have the wildcard (*) modifier by default.`, but in this case I don't really understand why your version did not work.

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to run that, but it throws an Invalid Hotkey Error on the line `*CapsLock & j::Send {Blind}{Down DownTemp}`

Comment: But I have used `#If GetKeyState("CapsLock", "P")`, and it works great

Comment: Glad, you've got it to work, thanks for the accepted answer! :) I have added an edit about the combined keys.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else stumbles upon this question, here's another way to do this that prevents all accidental Caps Lock toggling:

```
SetCapsLockState, AlwaysOff

#If GetKeyState("CapsLock", "P")
h::Left
j::Down
k::Up
l::Right
#If

*CapsLock::
KeyWait, CapsLock
IF A_ThisHotkey = *CapsLock
    Send, {Escape}
Return
```

Credit Rohwedder: https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=70880